# My speaker works fine, but have no more control from volume button

Tags: usb, sound, volume-control, speakers, arduino

I just bought a new computer and install Ubuntu 16 for the first time. Everything worked perfectly, sound control was fine, until I start playing with my arduino. I had to run some cmd to get it to work

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc7

Since then, I can't control my usb speakers anymore even if I can see the sound progess bar changing in the upper right corner and my speakers is playing fine. I can only control from the volume control in media player volume control.

Anyone can help?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: BTW, I am using a bluetooth usb keyboard Logitech K330 to control the sound.

Comment: you can edit your question.